# How to preg_split square brackets and group them into array

Tags: php, arrays, regex, ini, preg-split

I have a .ini file to be read in PHP and would like to convert them into multidimensional-array.

**Input**:

```
[101]
DestName=Person A
dstaddr=+880071268
smbody=This Is Testing 1
response=http://localhost/reply.php
[102]
DestName=Person B
dstaddr=+890071268
smbody=This Is Testing 2
[103]
.
.
.
```

I want to get an array out from it with regular expression preg_split:

**Expected Output**:

```
[
 "101": [
     DestName: "Person A"
     dstaddr: "+880071268"
     response: "http://localhost/reply.php"
     smbody: "This Is Testing 1"
    ]
 "102": [
     DestName: "Person B"
     dstaddr: "+890071268"
     smbody: "This Is Testing 2"
    ]
]
```

I have read some answers from here and tried the code as following to get the other output.

```
$num = preg_split("#\[[^\]]+\]\r\n#", $fread, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

foreach ($num as $skey => $str){
    foreach (explode("\r\n", $str) as $key => $line) {
        $l = explode('=', trim($line));
        if (isset($l[1])){
            $arr[$skey][$l[0]] = $l[1];
        }
    }
}
```

**My Output**:

```
[
 0: [
     DestName: "Person A"
     dstaddr: "+880071268"
     response: "http://localhost/reply.php"
     smbody: "This Is Testing 1"
    ]
 1: [
     DestName: "Person B"
     dstaddr: "+890071268"
     smbody: "This Is Testing 2"
    ]
]
```

Notice that I can't get the value inside the square bracket (*e.g. 101 in [101]*) and convert into the key for my array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be much easier to just use the built-in [`parse_ini_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php):

```
$result = parse_ini_file("myfile.ini", true)
```

Comment: I second that, parse_ini_file() does exactly what you need

Comment: thanks @Darthur, your answer helps to solve my problem!

Comment: It's actually @Mureinik's answer, I am just approving his message since he managed to post it seconds before me :D You should also mark his answer as Accepted

Comment: thanks to @Mureinik for the solution!